BCI (brain-computer interfaces) to retrieve contents of dreams
I would like to know whether brain-computer interfaces can be used to relieve the content of dreams.
If so, then what about dreams made in the past. Would such dreams still lie encoded in the brain, somehow (thus making them subject of retrieval)?
Thank you for your input.
